# async await on anonamous methods

Tags: c#, .net

This works

```
Task <string> t = Task <string> .Factory.StartNew(() => {
    return "test";
});
```

but if I change this to the below gives complilation error why?

```
Task <string> t = Task <string> .Factory.StartNew(asyc() => {
    await Thread.sleep(10000);
    return "test";
});
```

Comment: you might want to include what the compilation error is

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` returns void so there's nothing to await.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your issue is that the `async` method does not return a `string` but a `Task<string>`. So the correct return value for your function would be a `Task<Task<string>>`. Be aware that the outer task will be marked as completed as soon as the inner task is created and from that point forward you would have to wait for the inner task.

I suggest you are not using `Task.Factory.StartNew` but rather `Task.Run` since this function has a overload that properly handles `async` inner functions and unwraps the tasks. Using `Task.Run` is a good general idea, since you rarely need the `Task` created the way that `Task.Factory.StartNew` does.

So I suggest you change the code to:

```
Task<string> t = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        return "test";
    });
```

But if you are sure that you want to use `Task.Factory.StartNew` you can use this:

```
Task<Task<string>> t = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        return "test";
    });
```

*EDIT:* Just spotted that you are wrongly using `Thread.Sleep`. You need something that returns a `Task` to await it (or rather a awaitable object).

The function that does that for a delay is `Task.Delay`. This gives you a `Task` that can be awaited that completes after a set time.

Comment: The better thing to do if you really must use StartNew would be `Task<string> t = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => ...).Unwrap();`. However if you are not using a overload that does not take in a `TaskSchedueller` or a `TaskCreationOptions` you should ***NOT*** be using StartNew and should be using `Task.Run` instead.